# Shortcuts to make it easier to change between Sidecar and Universal Control in Monterey and iPadOS?

Tags: keyboard, ipad, ipados, sidecar, universal-control

Currently I don't see a quick way to flip between using an iPad as an additional display or in using Universal Control (controlling it with macOS keyboard and mouse) with the current tooling of macOS 12.5.

Has anyone found a quick way to switch between these aside from using the "System Preferences → Displays → Add Display" button?

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the difference between Universal Control and extending the display to an iPad, but you can add Screen Mirroring to your menu bar for quick access to these settings.